# Core Text with scaling transformation

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-text

In my program, I am trying to draw a text using Core Text with some scaling so that I can draw shrunk or expanded text.

I faced the problem that rectangle containing text also get scaled. But what I want is that the text should start from the same point.

So, to avoid scaling of the rectangle, I used following method

```
//Translate by (-pX, 0) so that origin does not scale.
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -pX, 0);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, pScale, 1);
//Translate by (pX, 0) so that origin comes at pX
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, pX, 0);

CTFrameDraw(frame, context);

//Reverse the transformations.
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -pX, 0);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1/pScale, 1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, pX, 0);
```

But this does not work. How to display scaled texts so that normal texts and scaled texts starts drawing from the same point.

Please see the image below for the output.

[image: Output]

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? If so... could you possibly give a bit more info? In your image, where did you expect the various strings to be drawn in relation to where they are? And can you show the rest of the code that creates the CTFramesetter and CTFrame.